# Can an infant sense if their mother is pregnant

Tags: pregnancy

I have a 7 month son - he has became super clingy to me but gets very fussy with others including his father. Every time I feed him(breastfeeding) he always wants to put his butt in the air and recently my nephew has wanted to sleep with me and also put his butt in the air.

Every time I go to the doctors they say I'm not pregnant, and every pregnancy test and blood test all say negative however I have started feeling movements in my stomach and my son blows on my stomach and yells at it when I start feeling nauseous and feeling any type of way. I have many symptoms of pregnancy but everything says negative.

Can my 7 month son feel/sense if I were pregnant?

Comment: 7 months is an age at which the first stages of separation anxiety show, that's probably why your son is clingy. Also, babies put their bottoms up into the air to strengthen their legs in preparation for crawling and walking.

Comment: It's possible for there to be separation anxiety at seven months, but it's quite unusual. It most often happens between 10-18 months.

Comment: Almost 4 years later, the cliffhanger is killing me. Were you pregnant?

Answer (score 11):

All evidence suggests that no, your infant can not sense your pregnancy. What they are very sensitive to, however, are your own moods and activities. Your behaviour (and the behaviour of those around you) is going to be one of the main reasons for behaviours you see from your child (in addition to the inherent nursing behaviours etc)

I'm having to disregard the implicit question in your 2nd paragraph - there is no way we on the Internet can give you a better diagnosis of pregnancy than your doctor and the pregnancy tests you have run (which should give you an almost 100% accuracy) - it is not uncommon to feel symptoms of pregnancy, and indeed various illnesses, as your body is going through many changes in hormones. For your reassurance, continuing to use pregnancy checks each month is an easy way to check with a very high degree of accuracy, or if you are really concerned, your doctor may be able to carry out an ultrasound.

Answer (score 4):

If you're far enough along to feel movement, it will clearly--100% chance-- show on ultrasound. So--to address a key part of your question--it's not possible that you're pregnant. To address the rest of your question: no, the child can't sense embryonic fetuses.

You might want to read up on the stages of development in the first year. A lot is happening *every week*, and your seven-month-old is in a key transitional phase.